# DOM . Jquery. Задать стиль дочернему элементу

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
.grid-item*2>(img^.grid-content)
```

При наведении курсора на блок .grid-item надо чтоб на ЕГО дочерний элемент .grid-content добавлялся класс. короче, мне надо дойти до второго дочернего элемента

Спасибо за ранее, но вопрос нубский конечно

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="box__item"></div>
  <div class="box__item"></div>
</div>
```

```
.box {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;

  &__item {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
}
```

```
$(".box__item:nth-child(2)").css("background", "red");
```